# Shell command in backticks behaves differently than CLI

Tags: ruby, shell

Ruby 2.1.5 (or 1.8.7, or 1.9.3), OS X 10.10

I've used the find command like the following for eons to strip away OS-specific hidden folders, svn folders, etc.

`find /somewhere -type f -name '.DS_Store' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rdf`

However, when automating with Ruby, like this (in backticks):

`find #{@copies_folder} -type f -name '.DS_Store' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rdf`

find gags and the message "illegal option -- t" is displayed. Note the -- is followed by a space.

It seems plausible to me that -type is being misinterpreted as -t, and therefore flagged as invalid. Since there's no `--type` alternate form, I don't see any way to monkey with the command string itself.

I've tried using `%x[]` and `popen3` as alternate approaches, but getting the same reaction.

I've automated a lot of shell commands in Ruby successfully, but this one I can't figure out. The version of Ruby doesn't seem to matter.

Any ideas or suggestions on some other way to skin this cat? Many thx.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce... I get ``find /app -type f -name '.DS_Store' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rdf`` with output: ""

Comment: What is the value of `@copies_folder`?

Comment: `@copies_folder` is a path of..... e-friggin-gads. Just went to print it out (again, done it before) and through a quirk of fate, it was empty. Arrrrgh. Sorry to have you waste cycles on this. "What a maroon" -- Bugs (Now I have to go try to answer two questions to bring the universe back into balance.)

Comment: I didn't see your comment, and when running some tests, I got the same error in the shell when I did this:  `find -type f -name 1.*`.  t

Comment: I didn't see your comment, and I was running some tests, and by accident I executed the following in the shell: `find -type f -name *.*`, and I got the same error you did from your ruby program.  Of course, that meant that your path,`#{@copies_folder}`, was nil or '' in your ruby program.